# Multi-dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there an available implementation of multi-dimensional array in C++ where the number of dimensions are specified at runtime? Basically, I am looking for something like this:

```
// create a 4 dimensional array 
int num_dim = 4; 
int sizes[4] = {3, 2, 4, 5}; // size for each dimension
MultiArray<int> A( num_dim, sizes ); 

// accessing a element in the array
int index[4] = {2, 2, 1, 0};
A[index] = 3;
```

Edit:
Notice that I don't want to use either `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` or `boost::multi_array` because I do not know the number of dimensions before hand.

Comment: `std::vector<int>` to the rescue! Also, [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

Comment: The problem is I don't know the number of dimensions before hand. I am looking for something more flexible.

Comment: Note that you can always wrap boost multi_array using your own class. Your class can construct a multi_array on construction and access it using its operator[].

Comment: @YuchenZhong: Do you really mean the number of dimensions, and not their sizes only?

Comment: I don't think there is such yet, sry. Still, should not be too difficult to create based on a `std::vector` for example.

Comment: What should happen if `operator[]` gets a container / array / etc. with the wrong number of indices?

Comment: @aschepler: It will be nice it will will show an [out-of-rang exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/). But that's not very important.

Comment: Could this be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)? Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the implementation exists in boost

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, though good try by user3477950. Or was that even in the first revision of the question?

Comment: I did modify my question after @user3477950's comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Notice that I don't want to use either `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` or `boost::multi_array` because I do not know the number of dimensions before hand.

Use of `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` is most appropriate for your situation.

```
int m;
int n;

// Read the dimensions of the 2D array.
std::cin >> m >> n;

// Create a 2D array of size m x n using `std::vector`.
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(m, std::vector<int>(n));
```